# Definition of Shrinks Nicely

Tags: real-analysis

The following is the definition of shrinks nicely according to Folland:

a family $\{E_r\}_{r>0}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ shrinks nicely to $x$ if $E_r \subset B(x,r)$ for all $r>0$ and $m(E_r) > \alpha m(B(x,r))$ for all $r>0$, for some universal constant $\alpha$.

I am confused about the indexing of the a family $\{E_r\}$.  Can there be a single E1 and that is the only set in the family?  Must the r converge to 0?  Must the index be uncountable?

Thank you for the help

Comment: As stated, the family must be indexed by $(0, \infty)$, so there is a set $E_r$ for each $r > 0$. I am not sure what the context is, but I think one can relax this definition by considering families indexed by any set of positive reals $r$ that has zero as a limit point.

Comment: (a "just passing by" comment) I wonder why Folland uses the potentially misleading phrase "for some universal constant $\alpha$?" When I see this phrase, my thoughts immediately go to something like $\pi,$ or $e,$ or $\ln (\pi - \sqrt{5}),$ etc. and only after spending a few moments rereading the definition and thinking of what makes sense do I realize all that is intended is that the existential quantifier "there exists $\alpha$" comes before the universal quantifier "for all $r,$ and then I waste time wondering why the author didn't just phrase it that way. **(continued)**

Comment: For example, why not just say "there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that for each $r>0$ we have $E_r \subset B(x,r)$ and $m(E_r) > \alpha m(B(x,r))$"? This is shorter and easier to parse mathematically, even with the additional assumption that $\alpha$ is positive (which I assume Folland intended, although maybe I'm wrong).